# Windows Application/process CPU usage including history

Tags: windows, central-processing-unit

I'm looking for a tool that can help me figure out what application/process that is using my CPU?

Issue: Some evenings, one server uses 100% CPU. Only some, and never in working hours.

(OS: Windows Server 2012)

Tools I have tried:

- Task Manager - Only real time
- Resource Manager: Only real time
- Process Explorer from sysinternals: Only real time
- Performance Monitor/perfmon: Can log to a file, but only shows me that CPU usage goes to 100% - can't tell me the actual process causing it...

Is there a windows tool or 3rd party tool that can help me?

Comment: Looks like it. I will give it a try, and update here tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @PJ: Worked fine, thanks. Please post an answer so I can mark it as answer. (My problem was the TSM backup (As expected, but nice to get it confirmed))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RESOURCE ANSWER:** https://superuser.com/questions/453909/log-cpu-by-process-over-time *(Please ensure to uptick on the article link answer for its credit as well)*

**Software Download Link:** [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

1. Enable collections of profiling events
2. `Options` | `Profiling Events`
3. `Thread Profiling Options` *window* --> *Check* `Generate Thread Profiling Events`
4. Start collecting data for your time period needs. Set up *filters* and enable drop filtered events when collecting extended periods of time. Then go to `Tools` | `Process Activity Summary`:
5. You should get a list of all active processes you recorded, with their activity over time.
6. Open the details for a single process by double-clicking on it, and inspect the timestamps for certain events in the graph.

Comment: Worked as I needed, thanks!
Remember to remove registry, file and network from monitor and then set the "drop filters events", otherwise log will be very large. I did it, and still got 16Gb over a 12 hour period.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Performance Monitor**, you're right that monitoring **Processor** will only show you CPU usage. To find what is using the CPU you want to to monitor **Process**. Add **Process** > **% Processor** Time and choose **`<All Instances>`**

Comment: Almost works... 
It seems like it only monitors the processes that are running at the time when I start the monitor.
But I didn't know, and it is a good fast way to get some more info on individual processes. Thanks